# C# Diferentes tipos de tamaño de fuente en Excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

tengo una situacion con un reporte que estoy elaborando en C# hacia Excel. No hay problemas con la informacion ni cuando se combinan celdas utilizando Merge. El problema viene con el tipo de fuente, alinear o asignar negrilla. Si hago lo siguiente:

```
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A3:BH3"] = "Laboratorio de Pruebas";
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A4:BH4"] = "Informe de Ensayos de Pruebas";
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A3:BH3"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A4:BH4"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A3:BH4"].Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A3:BH4"].Style.Font.Size = 12;
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A3:BH4"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A5"] = "Cliente:";
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A5"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A5"].Style.Font.Size = 10 ;
            Libro.Sheets[1].Range["A5"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

En teoria, deberia alinear centrado el título, tamaño 12 Arial con negrilla y dos lineas mas abajo un subtitulo alineado a la izquierda, tamaño 10 negrilla pero no lo hace: coloca TODO el reporte con el ultimo formato que coloques, en este caso Arial 10 negrilla alineado a la izquierda.

Ya probé antes de hacer el merge, antes de escribir el texto, o al final cuando creo todo el reporte. Reviso ejemplos y son tal cual como estoy mostrando aqui. Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que codificar del siguiente modo aplicando estilos, tal como indica el artículo de [MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-apply-styles-to-ranges-in-workbooks?view=vs-2022):

```
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            Excel.Workbook Libro = app.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel.Worksheet ws = Libro.Sheets.Add();
            ws.Activate();
            // definir un estilo:
            Excel.Style style = Libro.Styles.Add("estilo1");
            style.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            style.Font.Name = "Arial";
            style.Font.Size = 12;
            style.Font.Bold = true;
            Excel.Range rng = ws.Range["A3:BH3"];
            rng.Value2 = "Laboratorio de Pruebas";
            // aplicar el estilo al rango:
            rng.Style = "estilo1";

            rng = ws.Range["A4:BH4"];
            rng.Value2 = "Informe de Ensayos de Pruebas";
            rng.Style = "estilo1";

            // definir otro estilo:
            Excel.Style style2 = Libro.Styles.Add("estilo2");
            style2.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
            style2.Font.Name = "Arial";
            style2.Font.Size = 10;
            style2.Font.Bold = true;
            rng = ws.Range["A5"];
            rng.Value2 = "Cliente:";
            rng.Style = "estilo2";
```

Comment: No amigo no funciona. En Vb .Net sin usar select lo hace tal cual pero en este caso, toda la hoja de excel se convierte en el ultimo formato que se selecciona. No respeta la anterior

Comment: Tenías razón. He editado el código con la solución que da Microsoft para aplicar estilos.